# Posting value through form hidden field in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$student_no = $_GET['student_no'];
echo '<form  name="student" action="PROCESS_FEE007.php" method="POST">';
echo '</br><table>';
echo '**<input name="student_no" type="hidden" value="$student_no"  />**';
echo '<td>Amount: </td><td>'.'<input name="amount" type="text" /></td></tr>'; 
echo '<tr> <td>Remarks: </td><td>'.'<input name="remarks" type="text"  /> </td>';
echo '<tr> <td>';
echo '<td>'.'<input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

On the next page `PROCESS_FEE007.PHP` the value is not received.

Comment: You should read it with `$_POST['student_no']` (in PROCESS_FEE007.PHP) as you're using POST method in the form..

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the value? Can you also post the generated html for the page? Also the page that links to this php script should send the `student_no` properly as a **GET** parameter

Comment: maby `var_dump($_POST)` from PROCESS_FEE007.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using $_REQUEST instead of get example $student_no = $_REQUEST['student_no'];

Answer (score 4):

Variables are not parsed by interpreter inside single quotes. You should use double quotes or explicit string concatenation.

In your example the value of `$_POST['student_no']` will be string `'$student_no'`, not the value of the `$student_no` variable.

Besides if you're using `method="POST"` in your form, you can only get the inputs value through the `$_POST` array.

```
<?php
$student_no = $_POST['student_no'];
echo '<form  name="student" action="PROCESS_FEE007.php" method="POST">';
echo '</br><table>';
echo '**<input name="student_no" type="hidden" value="'.$student_no.'"  />**';
echo '<td>Amount: </td><td>'.'<input name="amount" type="text" /></td></tr>'; 
echo '<tr> <td>Remarks: </td><td>'.'<input name="remarks" type="text"  /> </td>';
echo '<tr> <td>';
echo '<td>'.'<input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: I have edited your post to format the inline code. I have also corrected a statement: When using method `POST`, the input values can only be accessed through `$_POST`. The `$_GET` object only contains references to the parameters which are appended to the query string.

Comment: @rob-w, not only, they can also be accessed using `$_REQUEST`. Besides, we don't know what method is used to pass the `student_no` to the initial script - that's why I added comment `// GET or POST`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem was in echo '**<input name="student_no" type="hidden" value="'.$student_no.'"  />**'; the $student_no was not inclosed in single quotes with concatinated dosts.

Answer (score 1):

parse student_no in form as

```
<?php
$student_no = $_GET['student_no'];

echo '<form  name="student" action="PROCESS_FEE007.php" method="POST">';
echo '</br><table>';
echo '**<input name="student_no" type="hidden" value="'.$student_no.'"  />**';
echo '<td>Amount: </td><td>'.'<input name="amount" type="text" /></td></tr>'; 
echo '<tr> <td>Remarks: </td><td>'.'<input name="remarks" type="text"  /> </td>';
echo '<tr> <td>';
echo '<td>'.'<input type="submit" name="submit_save" value="Save"/></td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

and on the PROCESS_FEE007.php page use

```
<?php 
 if ($_POST['submit_save']){
    var_dump($_POST);die();
}
```

?>

Comment: or by using `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 1):

check the attribute "VALUE" of hidden input field. The value is not put in the field.

First make the input field a text box and after fixing the bug make it a hidden field.

may be useful. (I forgot cuz I am out of PHP long time).