# Submit form to php page and carry over POST data to redirect page

Tags: php, post

I have found some general info on this question but nothing seems to answer my exact question.

I have a form on a .php page, that when submitted POST's the inputs to another php page, which sends the form inputs to my email and then redirects to another php page using (Location: page.php)

so: form.php --> email.php (hidden) --redirect--> submitted.php

I would like to have an input from form.php be carried over to a hidden input box on submitted.php

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance for your help!

edit:

on submitted.php I will have a single hidden form input. I need the value of that input to be equal to one of the inputs from form.php. I will then POST that input to another php page (not seen above) that will send it to my email.

Comment: Hey SirBdon Sorry... brain's gone to mush tonight :(

Comment: understood the question , however , would appreciate if you could post what have you tried so far

Comment: I have a good feeling on what you wish to do, I just can't get my brain into gear. Call it "fatigue". Let's see if someone else can help, I am just plum tuckered out. But in a nutshell, you'd basically need to use that 1st variable and pass it on to the next, then in your processor, use that 2nd variable as your final POST value.

Comment: Do you need final page (submitted.php) to receive the input as $_POST? Or is another method (GET/sessions/etc) acceptable?

Comment: Well he'd almost have to use GET or session, unless he wants to change his flow.

Comment: @prodigitalson yeah that's what I'm thinking, unless he wants to use javascript on email.php to submit a second form instead of doing the header redirect.

Comment: @Mailcolm see edit above.
Fred no worries! you've been great help before

Comment: @SirBdon Thanks, it was a pleasure. I started on something but I'll get to it tomorrow and check if you've gotten an answer you can use. Take care, cheers (*Peace*)

Comment: @SirBdon Well my friend, I thought it over and couldn't come up with a solution for you. Can you tell me what the reason is, maybe I can come up with a different method. *You picked my brain, lol*

Comment: @SirBdon From what I gathered, you need to pass one variable to another. This may be the scenario -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11058777/1415724 (`$tables_array=$this->input->post('tables');`) as an example.

Comment: @SirBdon Another example which fits the bill: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8635020/1415724

Comment: @SirBdon Here's another question/answers that could be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element

Comment: @SirBdon Ok, I came up with a possible solution and is the best I could do. I made up a Pastebin file, but **you need to be a "member"** to view it, and will expire in one week. [**Here is the link**](http://pastebin.com/yEe9s9gm), and let me know if this will work. Now I have to get some work done (wink) (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, put your sending email code in your submitted.php code and using sessions prevent user from duplicating his input by pressing F5 or refreshing submitted.php as follows:

in form.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['submit'] = true;
```

in submited.php

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['submit']) && $_SESSION['submit']){

/*
* do your code
*/
  $_SESSION['submit'] = false;
}
else{
  echo 'some error';
}
```

Comment: If I understand that correctly it will send submitted.php as soon as form.php is submitted? Unfortunately I need the user to input more data in submitted.php before sending

Comment: @SirBdon However, the sequence you regarded in the question stated that email sending is separated action from final submitted!